# Custom framework objective c use cocoapods frameworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I have created a custom framework in objective c and I add a podfile with opentok and swiftsignalrclient. I use this framework in the objective c project see the below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3tuw.png)

I have an issue when running projects.

1. not find opentok. I created a podfile in the project with opentok and I have this warning objc[1491]: Class OTSubscriber is implemented in both custom framework and project. This happens with all classes of OpenTok.
2. I use also swiftsignalrclient in the framework and I project not find this library so I copy-paste swiftsignalrclient framework to the project and added it to libraries and embedded content. I solve the problem but is there any way that the project sees cocoapods libraries of my custom framework?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngoCF.png)
   and podfile custom framework
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmNOA.png)

I Would appreciate to give me your lights, please.

Comment: You should properly setup yours dependencies in podspec file

Comment: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency